# Managing iptables for specific ips and ports

Tags: linux, ssh, security, iptables, http

I disable firewall like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

## Update

I also enable my firewall:

```
 #!/bin/bash

ssh=x.x.x.x
http='x.x.x.x y.y.y.y'

# Clear any previous rules.
iptables -F

# Default drop policy.
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow anything over loopback.
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT

# Drop any tcp packet that does not start a connection with a syn flag.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

# Drop any invalid packet that could not be identified.
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP

# Drop invalid packets.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN              -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST              -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST              -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,FIN FIN                  -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG                  -j DROP

# Allow TCP/UDP connections out. Keep state so conns out are allowed back in.
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow only ICMP echo requests (ping) in. Limit rate in. Uncomment if needed.
iptables -A INPUT  -p icmp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED --source $ssh -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP

for web in $http; do
    iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED --source $web -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DROP
done


# or block ICMP allow only ping out
iptables -A INPUT  -p icmp -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT  -p icmp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

So I want just `x.x.x.x` be able to ssh to me. and also I want the follwing ips to see my `80,443` ports:

```
x.x.x.x
y.y.y.y
```

how can I change it?

Comment: Can you post the output of `iptables -L -n -v` after you've run your firewall setup script?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to move the lines that change the policy to DROP to the end of the script. If you're connected to that machine via ssh *you* will get dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are putting your rules in the wrong order. In iptables, the `-A` *appends* to the chain, not inserts it before it. Normally, you have ...

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
```

*and then*

```
# Drop any tcp packet that does not start a connection with a syn flag.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

Instead of changing the order, you could rewrite it with `-I INPUT 1`, so that each rule is inserted before the previous one, ie, at the top. But the tail ping/icmp rules will have to be moved in that case.

Now, back to your question:

```
iptables -N SSH_CHECK
iptables -N HTTP_CHECK

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j SSH_CHECK
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j HTTP_CHECK
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j HTTP_CHECK

iptables -A SSH_CHECK -s x.x.x.x -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "allow joe to ssh from his IP"
iptables -A HTTP_CHECK -s y.y.y.y -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "allow mary to visit my HTTP/S server"
```

Your default drop policy takes care of the non-conforming IPs.